# How would I go about generating a number from a range, and making it so that each possibility in the range has a different probability?

Tags: r

I want to figure out how to generate a number from a range, where each item in the range has a different probability of it being generated.

For instance, I want the chances to be:

```
p=c(.1,.2,.3,.35, .02, .03)
```

For a range of 1-6.

I believe I need to use cumsum, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Is it like this ? `sample(1:6, 100, replace = T, prob = c(.1,.2,.3,.35, .02, .03))`

Comment: `sample(1:6, 1, prob=p)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `sample()` function for this. For a range of 1-6 and your specified chances it would look like:

```
sample(x = 1:6, size = 1, prob = c(.1, .2, .3, .35, .02, .03))
```

For more information and arguments you can check out `?sample`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for the answer. Next time please learn how to format code, both inline and code blocks. (Don't worry, I have done that for you.) I also believe that the answer would be more complete if you quote the help page you mention, in particular the part where it says that the probabilities must add up to 1 or will be made to add up to 1.

Comment: Brilliant answer, I really appreciate the help.